# $router.push Not Working?

Tags: vuejs2

so I'm using [iViewUI](https://www.iviewui.com/) with VueJS for a small proyect. So far everything is going great. Unfortunately I'm having a bit of a problem with `$router.push()`.

I want to push to a new URL when a card is clicked. This is my code:

```
<Card :bordered="true" @click="$router.push('/my/cool/link')">
  <p slot="title">Card Title</p>
  <p>Card description</p>
</Card>
```

So, the problem is when I click the card nothing happens, this is the first time this has happened to me when working with VueJS. Anyone know why this could be happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the `@click` event inside the first element of the `Card` component?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried it @RuChernChong and still nothing. :(

Comment: Then you may want to add a method which handles the click.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using `@click.native="$router.push('/my/cool/link')"` on the `Card` component.

Answer (score 0):

```
<card :bordered="true" @click="handleClick">
  <p slot="title">Card Title</p>
  <p>Card description</p>
</Card>
```

---

```
export default {
  // Whatever you got here
  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$router.push('/my/cool/link')
    }
}
```

### route.js

```
export default new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/my/cool/link' }
  ]
})
```

Feel free to rename the methods based on your liking.

Comment: I don't see why that didn't work. You probably have to set the click handler in the child component and use the `$emit()` function to send the even up. Or just directly click it from the child component itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<card :bordered="true" @click="handleClick">

methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.$router.push('/my/cool/link')
    }
```

or

```
<v-btn to="/my/cool/link">Next Page</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use following codes for change route in Nuxtjs.

```
this.$router.push("/");
or
this.$router.push({ path: '/'} );
```

Suppose, In case if your now viewing this link "http://localhost:3000" or "http://192.168.0.102:300" and trying to change route by push using given code to route "/". so it will not working. Because, you already viewing this route. So, Nuxtjs route cant not change.

For handling this case you can using following technique/code inside your methods:

vuejs way:

```
if($route.path == '/') {
   //following 2 line code are sample code here put your need codes
   this.isLogin = false;
   this.user_full_name = 'My Account';
} else {
   // this.$router.push("/");
   this.$router.push({ path: '/'} );
}
```

=============================================

nuxtjs way:

```
if($nuxt.$route.path == '/') {
   //following 2 line code are sample code here put your need codes
   this.isLogin = false;
   this.user_full_name = 'My Account';
} else {
   // this.$router.push("/");
   this.$router.push({ path: '/'} );
}
```